# How to select columns from dataframe outside of a range?

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I specify a range of columns plus an additional column that's outside of a range using this type of format/notation?

```
# this specifies range of columns 2-5
is.na( dataset [,2:5])

# I would like to specify for columns 2-5 and column 12 within a single line like this
is.na( dataset [,2:5 & 12])
```

Comment: See answer below but you might also do `dplyr::select(dataset, 2:5 | 12)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `c` to concatenate:

```r
is.na(dataset[, c(2:5, 12)])
```